# How do I pass data from a child view to a parent view to another child view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, combine

as the title suggests, I'm trying to pass data from one child view (A), to another child view (B) through the parent view (P).

The parent view looks like this:

```
@State var rectFrame: CGRect = .zero 

var body: some View {
    childViewA(rectFrame: $rectFrame)
    childViewB()
}
```

where `childViewA` obtains a `CGRect` that `childViewB` needs.

`childViewA` looks like this:

```
@Binding var rectFrame: CGRect

var body: some View {
    // Very long code where rectFrame is obtained and printed to console correctly
}
```

How do I pass `rectFrame` to `childViewB`? Everything I've tried so far returns `CGRect.zero` in `childViewB` despite printing the correct values in both the `parentView` and `childViewA`.

In order to try and pass the value to `childViewB`, I've rewritten `parentView` like this:

```
@State var rectFrame: CGRect = .zero 

var body: some View {
    childViewA(rectFrame: $rectFrame)
    childViewB(rectFrame: $rectFrame.value)
}
```

with `childViewB` having the following structure:

```
var rectFrame: CGRect = CGRect.zero

var body: some View {

}
```

But that just prints `CGRect.zero` every time.

I've recently tried `@ObjectBinding` but I've struggled with it, so if anyone could help me out with this specific example, I'd be very grateful.

```
class SourceRectBindings: BindableObject {
    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var sourceRect: CGRect = .zero {
        willSet {
            willChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the frame?  It should only be set via a) PreferenceKey or b) DispatchQueue.main.async { ... } or the changes won't be propagated.

Comment: @arsenius PreferenceKey

Comment: Maybe check your implementation?  I've been using [this](https://gist.github.com/timothycosta/9e61418b3a4096c0f08cbe838357cabd) a lot just fine.  `.background(GeometryBinder(rect: self.$childFrame))`.

Comment: Also, this looks a little suspicious: `childViewB(rectFrame: $rectFrame.value)`.  Why not just `self.rectFrame`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*You can use [EnvironmentObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject) for stuff like this...*

*The nice thing about [EnvironmentObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject) is that whenever and wherever you change one of it's variables, it will always make sure that every where that variable is used, it's updated.*

> Note: To get every variable to update, you have to make sure that you pass through the BindableObject class / EnvironmentObject on everyView you wish to have it updated in...

**SourceRectBindings:**

```
class SourceRectBindings: BindableObject {

    /* PROTOCOL PROPERTIES */
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Application, Never>()

    /* Seems Like you missed the 'self' (send(self)) */
    var sourceRect: CGRect = .zero { willSet { willChange.send(self) }
}
```

---

**Parent:**

```
struct ParentView: view {
    @EnvironmentObject var sourceRectBindings: SourceRectBindings

    var body: some View {
        childViewA()
            .environmentObject(sourceRectBindings)
        childViewB()
            .environmentObject(sourceRectBindings)
    }
}
```

---

**ChildViewA:**

```
struct ChildViewA: view {
    @EnvironmentObject var sourceRectBindings: SourceRectBindings

    var body: some View {

        // Update your frame and the environment...
        // ...will update the variable everywhere it was used

        self.sourceRectBindings.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)
        return Text("From ChildViewA : \(self.sourceRectBindings.sourceRect)")
    }
}
```

---

**ChildViewB:**

```
struct ChildViewB: view {
    @EnvironmentObject var sourceRectBindings: SourceRectBindings

    var body: some View {
        // This variable will always be up to date
        return Text("From ChildViewB : \(self.sourceRectBindings.sourceRect)")
    }
}
```

**LAST STEPS TO MAKE IT WORK**

• Go into your highest view you want the variable to update which is your parent view but i usually prefer my **SceneDelegate** ... so this is how i usually do it:

`let sourceRectBindings = SourceRectBindings()`

• Then in the same class 'SceneDelegate' is go to where i specify my root view and pass through my EnviromentObject

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(
                rootView: ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(sourceRectBindings)
            )
```

• Then for the last step, I pass it through to may Parent view

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var sourceRectBindings: SourceRectBindings

    var body: some View {
        ParentView()
            .environmentObject(sourceRectBindings)
    }
}
```

> If you run the code just like this, you'll see that your preview throws errors. Thats because it didn't get passed the environment variable.
>   To do so just start a dummy like instance of your environment:

```
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(SourceRectBindings())
    }
}
#endif
```

**Now you can use that variable how ever you like and if you want to pass anything else other that the rect ... you can just add the variable to the EnvironmentObject class and you can access and update it**

Answer (score 7):

You did not mention how ChildViewB obtains its rect. That is, does it use a GeometryReader, or any other source. Whatever method you use, you can pass information upwards the hierachy in two ways: through a binding, or through preferences. And if geometry is involved, even anchor preferences.

For the first case, without seeing your implementation, you may be missing a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` when setting the rect. This is because the change must occur **after** the view finished updating itself. However, I consider that a dirty, dirty trick and only use it while testing, but never on production code.

The second alternative (using preferences), is a more robust approach (and is preferred ;-). I will include the code for both approaches, but you should definetely learn more about preferences. I recently wrote an article, that you can find here: https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/

**First Method:** I do not recommend, passing geometry values upward the hierarchy, that will affect how other views draw. But if you insist, this is how you can make it work:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var rectFrame: CGRect = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildViewA(rectFrame: $rectFrame)
            ChildViewB(rectFrame: rectFrame)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildViewA: View {
    @Binding var rectFrame: CGRect

    var body: some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rectFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 30, height: 40)
        }

        return Text("CHILD VIEW A")
    }
}

struct ChildViewB: View {
    var rectFrame: CGRect = CGRect.zero

    var body: some View {
        Text("CHILD VIEW B: RECT WIDTH = \(rectFrame.size.width)")
    }
}
```

**Second Method**: Using Preferences

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGRect

    static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var rectFrame: CGRect = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildViewA()
            ChildViewB(rectFrame: rectFrame)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(MyPrefKey.self) {
            self.rectFrame = $0
        }

    }
}

struct ChildViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        return Text("CHILD VIEW A")
            .preference(key: MyPrefKey.self, value: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 30, height: 40))
    }
}

struct ChildViewB: View {
    var rectFrame: CGRect = CGRect.zero

    var body: some View {
        Text("CHILD VIEW B: RECT WIDTH = \(rectFrame.size.width)")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to get the size and position of a view, check the link I posted. It's plenty of examples.

Comment: I actually used your blog (so Preferences to answer your question) to obtain the CGRect info in childA which I successfully get in the parent view. Unfortunately it seems Preferences doesn't get the correct frame if the view is inside of a list?

Comment: @cyril Without looking at the code, I am unable to tell. Maybe it is a coordinate space issue? Or an alignment issue? If you update the question, I'll have a look.

Comment: Also note that using EnvironmentObject (like in the other answer) is a possible solution. I did not go that route, because I though you were intending to keep it encapsulated. But going through a more global approach is also a possibility.

Comment: Might be a coordinate space issue - if I recall Part 2 of your blog post uses another method that doesn't rely on coordinate spaces. I might give that a go eventually

Comment: Remember you can also name the coordinate space of a view, and when you use GeometryReader's `frame(in:CoordinateSpace)` method, you can use that name to create a rect in another view's coordinate space.

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

PhilipJacob's answer is great but there is an update to this API and I thought I'd mention it.

So if you want to use `BindableObject` that has been renamed/updated to `ObservableObject` and also `var willChange` becomes `var objectWillChange`

So his answer becomes:

```
import Combine

class SourceRectBindings: ObservableObject {

    /* PROTOCOL PROPERTIES */
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    /* Seems Like you missed the 'self' (send(self)) */
    var sourceRect: CGRect = .zero { willSet { objectWillChange.send(self) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I have understood your problem correctly which is to share information between two children. The approach that I have taken is to have @Binding variables in both children that share the same state, i.e. instantiate both with $rectFrame. That way both will always have the same value and not the value at instantiation.

In my case it was an array that was update in one child and displayed in a list in the other so SwiftUI took care of reacting to the changes. Maybe your case isn't so simple.